# Is there a melt command in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, unpivot, melt

Is there a Snowflake command that will transform a table like this:

```
a,b,c
1,10,0.1
2,11,0.12
3,12,0.13
```

to a table like this:

```
key,value
a,1
a,2
a,3
b,10
b,11
b,13
c,0.1
c,0.12
c,0.13
```

?

This operation is often called `melt` in other tabular systems, but the basic idea is to convert the table into a list of key value pairs.

There is an `UNPIVOT` in SnowSQL, but as I understand it `UNPIVOT` requires to manually specify every single column. This doesn't seem practical for a large number of columns.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but could you leverage something like this: https://github.com/jrideout/melt.js/blob/master/melt.js and wrap that into a Snowflake Javascript UDTF??  Might take some effort, but perhaps that'd work.  Otherwise, `UNPIVOT` statements can also be generated dynamically using a stored procedure and executed that way, if needed.  I believe `UNPIVOT` is the standard SQL way to do this...not just a Snowflake thing.

Comment: for large number of columns, use the metadata tables which gives you the column names that you want to unpivot/melt instead of writing out each column name of the table.

Comment: @MikeWalton "Dynamic UNPIVOT" could be performed with SQL only.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda good stuff, man!  Thanks.  I've never looked into this method before.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Snowflake's SQL is powerful enough to perform such operation without help of third-party tools or other extensions.

Data prep:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE t(a INT, b INT, c DECIMAL(10,2))
AS
SELECT 1,10,0.1
UNION SELECT 2,11,0.12
UNION SELECT 3,12,0.13;
```

[image]

Query(aka "dynamic" UNPIVOT):

```
SELECT f.KEY, f.VALUE
FROM (SELECT OBJECT_CONSTRUCT_KEEP_NULL(*) AS j FROM t) AS s
,TABLE(FLATTEN(input => s.j)) f
ORDER BY f.KEY;
```

Output:

[image]

---

How does it work?

1. Transform row into JSON(row 1 becomes `{ "A": 1,"B": 10,"C": 0.1 }`)
2. Parse the JSON into key-value pairs using FLATTEN

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach using stored procedure [Returning Tabular Data](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-python#label-stored-procedure-python-return-table) that wraps Python [pandas.melt()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE melt(tablename TEXT, id_vars ARRAY, value_vars ARRAY)
RETURNS TABLE()
LANGUAGE PYTHON
RUNTIME_VERSION = 3.8
PACKAGES =('snowflake-snowpark-python')
HANDLER = 'main'
AS
$$
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark

def main(session: snowpark.Session, tablename: str, id_vars: list, value_vars: list): 
    return session.create_dataframe( \
        session.table(tablename).to_pandas().melt(id_vars,value_vars))
$$;
```

Input data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE T(A INT, B INT, C DECIMAL(10,2))
AS
SELECT 1,10,0.1
UNION SELECT 2,11,0.12
UNION SELECT 3,12,0.13;

SELECT * FROM t;
```

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 0.1 |
| 2 | 11 | 0.12 |
| 3 | 12 | 0.13 |

---

Invoking stored procedure:

```
CALL melt('PUBLIC.T', NULL, NULL);
-- <=>
CALL melt('PUBLIC.T', [], ['A','B','C']);
/*
variable    value
A   1
A   2
A   3
B   10
B   11
B   12
C   0.1
C   0.12
C   0.13
*/
```

Further transformations on the result of stored procedure are possible:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID())) 
WHERE "variable" = 'A';
/*
variable    value
A   1
A   2
A   3
*/
```

Other possibilities:

```
CALL melt('PUBLIC.T', ['A'], ['B','C']);
/*
A   variable    value
1   B   10
2   B   11
3   B   12
1   C   0.1
2   C   0.12
3   C   0.13
*/


CALL melt('PUBLIC.T', [], ['B']);
/*
variable    value
B   10
B   11
B   12
*/
```

---

Extras: `unpivot_all`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE unpivot_all(tablename TEXT)
RETURNS TABLE()
LANGUAGE PYTHON
RUNTIME_VERSION = 3.8
PACKAGES =('snowflake-snowpark-python')
HANDLER = 'main'
AS
$$
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark

def main(session: snowpark.Session, tablename: str): 
    df = session.table(tablename)
    return df.unpivot("key", "value", df.columns)
$$;
```

All columns in the table should have the same data type

```
CALL unpivot_all('PUBLIC.T');
/*
VALUE   KEY
A   1
B   10
C   0.1
A   2
B   11
C   0.12
A   3
B   12
C   0.13
*/
```

Related: [unpivot(tablename TEXT, cols ARRAY)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75987369/5070879)