# Dynamically UNPIVOTing table

Tags: sql, pivot, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, unpivot

I've wrote some experimental code that dynamically unpivots that table in Snowflake by re-casting all columns to `VARCHAR` and creating a list of columns using the `LISTAGG` function. The procedure works; however, I would like to ask if it's possible to improve the syntax by:

1. Reducing the dependency on string manipulation inside the table
2. Is it possible to replace the ugly `REGEXP_REPLACE` call with a more elegant loop-based solution that would recast all required columns?

```sql
/* Dynamically Unpivot Table
 *
 *  The following procedure can be used to dynamically unpivot table without specifying column names.
 *  The code, will re-cast the columns into the varchar type and return the table with column name and
 *  column value.
 */
 
-- Procedure definition
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dynamic_unpivot(table_name TEXT)
    RETURNS TABLE(col_name STRING, col_val STRING)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    COMMENT = 'Dynamically unpivot table'
AS
DECLARE
    res RESULTSET;
    pivot_cols TEXT;
    pivot_cols_recast TEXT;
    recast_select_statement TEXT;
    select_statement TEXT;
BEGIN
    -- Capture columns to pivot through
    SHOW COLUMNS IN VIEW IDENTIFIER(:table_name);
    pivot_cols := (SELECT LISTAGG(DISTINCT "column_name", ', ') FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID())));
    pivot_cols_recast := (REGEXP_REPLACE(pivot_cols, '(\\b\\w+\\b)', '\\1::VARCHAR AS \\1'));
    recast_select_statement := 'SELECT ' || :pivot_cols_recast || ' FROM ' || :table_name ;
    select_statement := 'SELECT * FROM (' || :recast_select_statement || ' ) t_recast' ||
                            ' UNPIVOT (col_val ' || ' FOR col_name ' || ' IN (' || :pivot_cols || '))';
    res := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :select_statement);
    RETURN TABLE(res);
END;


-- Tests
-- Create temporary table
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_t1 (col_a VARCHAR, col_b NUMBER);

-- Insert some sample data
INSERT INTO tmp_t1 (col_a, col_b) VALUES
   ('one', 1),
   ('two', 2),
   ('three', 3),
   ('four', 4);

-- Test query running procedure
CALL dynamic_unpivot('tmp_t1');
SELECT * FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID())) ORDER by col_name;

-- Cleaning
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS dynamic_unpivot(TEXT);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_t1;
```

Comment: If the goal is to transform all columns into col_name/col_val then it is possible with much simpler SQL code: [Is there a melt command in Snowflake?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68562208/5070879)

Comment: @LukaszSzozda thank you for this suggestion. That’s possibly a viable answer and better to what I’ve. I would need to add recasting somewhere there but it’s a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using unpivot for this, you can use snowflake semi-structured data handling.

We can use `object_constuct_keep_null(*)` to gather all the columns in each row of the table into object representing the row.  Then use `lateral flatten` to perform the 'UNPIVOT' operation.  In my experience this is often performs faster than UNPIVOT as well but YMMV.

The SQL looks like this:

```
with wide as (select object_construct_keep_null(*) obj_row from tmp_t1)
select key col_name, value::varchar col_val
from wide, lateral flatten(input => obj_row)
order by 1,2;
```

If you still want this enclosed within a Stored-Procedure call it would look like this:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dynamic_unpivot(table_name TEXT)
    RETURNS TABLE(col_name STRING, col_val STRING)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    COMMENT = 'Dynamically unpivot table'
AS
DECLARE
    res RESULTSET;
    select_statement TEXT;
BEGIN
    select_statement := 'with wide as (select object_construct_keep_null(*) obj_row from '|| :table_name ||')'||
                        'select key col_name, value::varchar col_val '||
                        'from wide, lateral flatten(input => obj_row)'||
                        'order by 1,2';
    res := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :select_statement);
    RETURN TABLE(res);
END;
```

An alternative approach to keep the tablename dynamic, whilst returning a tabular output that you can use (i.e. instead of using `TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()))`, is to use a session variable and `identifier()` to enclose it in the query body.

```
SET table_name = 'tmp_t1';

with wide as (select object_construct_keep_null(*) obj_row from identifier($table_name))
select key col_name, value::varchar col_val
from wide, lateral flatten(input => obj_row)
order by 1,2;
```

You can even turn this into a 'dynamic' view that you can query from, provided you have set the session variable to something before the view creation.

```
create view dynamic_unpivot as
with wide as (select object_construct_keep_null(*) obj_row from identifier($table_name))
select key col_name, value::varchar col_val
from wide, lateral flatten(input => obj_row);
```

With this you can set table_name to any view/table that you want to unpivot and get the desired result. e.g.

```
SET table_name = 'different_table';

Select * from dynamic_unpivot order by 1,2;
```

NOTE: If you try and query the view without the table_name variable set you will get an error. `Session variable '$TABLE_NAME' does not exist`

Comment: Thanks, comprehensive answer and a lot of good pointers!