# Unpivot multiple measures columns in Snowflake fact table

Tags: sql, performance, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-insert, unpivot

I'm trying to unpivot a fact table with below structure

```
source : 
customer_id , product_id, week, measure1 , measure2 , measure3 ... measure10 
CUST_101,PROD_101, W10,10,20,30...100

to

target : 
customer_id , product_id,week,measure_code, measure_value
CUST_101,PROD_101, W10,'MSR1',10
CUST_101,PROD_101, W10,'MSR2',20
CUST_101,PROD_101, W10,'MSR3',30
CUST_101,PROD_101, W10,'MSR4',40
CUST_101,PROD_101, W10,'MSR5',50
CUST_101,PROD_101, W10,'MSR6',60
CUST_101,PROD_101, W10,'MSR7',70
CUST_101,PROD_101, W10,'MSR8',80
CUST_101,PROD_101, W10,'MSR9',90
CUST_101,PROD_101, W10,'MSR10',100

Data volume in  source table :  ~ 15 ~ 25  million records in incremental batches
```

I'm planning to  use  **UNION ALL**  approach as suggested in [Unpivot multiple columns in Snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64328749/unpivot-multiple-columns-in-snowflake)

INSERT into Target (customer_id , product_id,week,measure_code, measure_value)
select
customer_id , product_id,week,'MSR1',measure1
from source
union all
select
customer_id , product_id,week,'MSR2',measure2
from source
...
select
customer_id , product_id,week,'MSR10',measure10
from source

Is there a more optimal way to accomplish this?
I'm aiming for  the stored procedure to  finish running in 30 minutes and using a medium size warehouse.

Thanks,
Adarsh

Comment: INSERT ALL from the same table should be faster than separate UNION ALLs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72159364/5070879

Comment: @adarsh - did you try this already? Can you report results? Give us a starting point

Comment: this worked fine! 

source volume ~ 3 billion, 
target ( aggregated at higher level and about 15 measures unpivoted ) : 76 million

time taken : 3 to 4 minutes

thank you @LukaszSzozda !