# in postgresql, can I combine this into a single query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I have the below table of updates.....

| refer | event_date | column detail | event_type | cat1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | yesterday | abc | type 3 | cat x |
| 2 | last week | abc3 | type 11 | cat b |
| 2 | today | abc123 | type 4 | cat a |
| 2 | last month | xyz | type 22 | cat z |
| 2 | last year | wtf | type 11 | cat z |

so for refer = 2

abc123 is the latest update based on latest date.
abc3 is the latest update for event_type 11  and cat = b
xyz is the latest update for cat z

Is it possible to do this in a single query? the only way I can get my results is to use separate queries or cte's:

```
with cte1 as (
select  t.refer,
        t.detail
from    
        (
            select ch.refer,
                  ch.detail,
                    row_number() over (partition by refer order by event_date desc) as rn
            from    table  ch
            ) as latest
    where ch.rn = 1
)
cte2 as(
select  t.refer,
        t.detail
from    
        (
            select ch.refer,
                  ch.detail,
                    row_number() over (partition by refer order by event_date desc) as rn
            from    table  ch
            where   event_type = '11'
            and     cat = 'b'
            ) as latest
    where ch.rn = 1
)
cte3 as(
select  t.refer,
        t.detail
from    
        (
            select ch.ref,
                  ch.detail,
                    row_number() over (partition by refer order by event_date desc) as rn
            from    table  ch
            where   event_type = 'z'   
            ) as latest
    where ch.rn = 1
    and cat = 'z'
);
```

Comment: All three are searching over different sets of rows, so I would say "no". However, you can compress that big query quite a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can enumerate the three partitions with three `row_number`s, then pivot with conditional aggregation:

```
select refer,
    max(detail) filter(where rn1 = 1                                  ) detail,
    max(detail) filter(where rn2 = 1 and cat = 'z'                    ) detail2,
    max(detail) filter(where rn3 = 1 and cat = 'b' and event_type = 11) detail3
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by refer                  order by event_date desc) rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by refer, cat             order by event_date desc) rn2,
        row_number() over(partition by refer, event_type, cat order by event_date desc) rn3
    from mytable t
) t
group by refer
```

| refer | detail | detail2 | detail3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | abc123 | xyz | abc3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/m73RggLK)

Of course this assumes that you are storing your dates in a `date`-like datatype, not as strings such as `'today'` or `'last year'`.

---

Alternatively, if you want the results as rows rather than as columns, then we don't need aggregation:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by refer                  order by event_date desc) rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by refer, cat             order by event_date desc) rn2,
        row_number() over(partition by refer, event_type, cat order by event_date desc) rn3
    from mytable t
) t
where
    rn1 = 1
    or (rn2 = 1 and cat = 'z')
    or (rn3 = 1 and cat = 'b' and event_type = 11)
```

Comment: This looks good, and answers the question about creating a single query, I must find out more about FILTERing to as the doucmentation isnt clear. 
Now to see how it performs.......

Comment: @GMB Thank you for the comment. I got it all wrong.

Comment: @TheImpaler: welcome. It happens to me on a regular basis :), as yesterday in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76257557/unpivot-multiple-measures-columns-in-snowflake-fact-table/76257669#76257669

Comment: @GMB i forgot to mentoin that column_detail also has nulls in it which means that i need to add a not null to each row eg
row_number() over(partition by refer (where refer is not null) order by event_date desc) rn1,  

row_number() over(partition by refer, cat (where refer is not null) order by event_date desc) rn2

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION` (to eleminate duplicates when same date occur in more than one select ) :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM mytable t
INNER JOIN (
  select refer, max(event_date) as recent_date
  from mytable 
  where refer = 2 
  group by refer
  union
  select refer, max(event_date) as recent_date
  from mytable where event_type = 'type 11' and cat1 = 'cat b'
  group by refer
  union
  select refer, max(event_date) as recent_date
  from mytable
  where cat1 = 'cat z'
  group by refer
) AS s on s.refer = t.refer and s.recent_date = t.event_date
```

Result :

```
refer   event_date  column_detail   event_type  cat1
2       2023-05-08  abc3            type 11     cat b
2       2023-05-16  abc123          type 4      cat a
2       2023-04-16  xyz             type 22     cat z
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/aCsJmqUD)