# postgres eliminating NULLS in partition by group

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

**updated** 

I have the following table of updates which you will note contains nulls

| refer | event_date | col1 | col2 | col3 | cat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | today | null | null | bbb | a |
| 2 | yesterday | null | null | null | b |
| 2 | yesterday | null | xyz | null | b |
| 2 | last week | abc3 | null | null | z |
| 2 | two weeks ago | aab | null | null | z |
| 2 | last month | null | def | AAA | a |
| 2 | last year | vwy | aa123 | null | b |

so for refer = 2

- bbb is the latest update of col3 based on latest date for cat = a (today).
- xyz is the latest update of col2 based on date for cat = b (yesterday).
- abc3 is the latest update of col1 based on date for cat z (last week).

I had previously asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76264348/in-postgresql-can-i-combine-this-into-a-single-query) and accepted the following code which was kindly provided by @GMB and works fine if the above table has no NULLS.

```
select refer,
    max(col1) filter(where rn3 = 1 and cat = 'a') detail,
    max(col1) filter(where rn2 = 1 and cat = 'b') detail2,
    max(col1) filter(where rn1 = 1 and cat = 'z') detail3
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by refer,col3 order by event_date desc) rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by refer,col2 order by event_date desc) rn2,
        row_number() over(partition by refer,col1 order by event_date desc) rn3
    from mytable t
) t
group by refer
```

expected output:

| refer | col1 lastest | col2 latest | col3 latest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | bbb | xyz | abc3 |

The thing is it doesn't work if there are nulls in the columns and I cant figure out how to eliminate nulls from the window partition groups. If I could add **is not null** in the partition as shown below it would fix my problem eg:

```
select
row_number() over(partition by refer, col3 **(where col3 is not null)** order by event_date desc) rn1
,row_number() over(partition by refer, col2, ***(where col2 is not null)*** order by event_date desc) rn2
,row_number() over(partition by refer, col1, ***(where col1 is not null)*** order by event_date desc) rn3
```

Comment: Can you add the corresponding expected output?

Comment: Thanks for assistance, I've not got my question correct I will edit and repost

Comment: @lemon not yet but good try from SelVazi

Comment: Probably your sample data does not match the nature of your actual data. Consider checking where the solutions fail, and understand what makes them fail. Then update your data so that it would cause problems with these solutions.

Comment: My solution [works with this data](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tVrkqWS51RVHCbtoAm7cnb/2) tho, unless the expected output is not yet updated.

Comment: I agree your solution is working, I need to further investigate why it doesn't with 'real' data ......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To eliminate `null` values from being captured from all partitions, use the conditional order inside `row_number()`, Also partitions must be based on *refer* and *cat*:

```
select refer,
    MAX(col3) filter(where rn3 = 1 and cat = 'a') col1_lastest,
    MAX(col2) filter(where rn2 = 1 and cat = 'b') col2_lastest,
    MAX(col1) filter(where rn1 = 1 and cat = 'z') col3_lastest
from (
    select t.*,
      row_number() over(partition by refer,cat order by case when col3 is not null then 1 else 2 end, event_date desc) rn3,
      row_number() over(partition by refer,cat order by case when col2 is not null then 1 else 2 end, event_date desc) rn2,
      row_number() over(partition by refer,cat order by case when col1 is not null then 1 else 2 end, event_date desc) rn1
    from mytable t
) t
group by refer;
```

Result :

| refer | col1_lastest | col2_lastest | col3_lastest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | bbb | xyz | abc3 |

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/SmhFzv3V)

Comment: what happens when the first record of a partition has detail set to null, with this solution?

Comment: Then the following record will be taken.

Comment: I'm not sure that would be correct for the OP, although it's better to wait for some clarification.

Comment: sorry question updated

Comment: I had high-hopes for this solution but I'm seeing multiple rows with rn?=1 
where there are more that one match for cat='a and likewise for the other rows 

try adding a value 'AAA' to col3 for "last month" and you will see what I mean

Comment: My solution is working with your latest edited data ! https://dbfiddle.uk/SmhFzv3V

Comment: scrub my last comment, this solution works fine. thankyou @SelVazi